# Qual é a diferença entre wait() e sleep()?

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

O significado das duas palavras parece bem parecido.

Qual é a diferença entre `wait()` e `sleep()`? Quando usar cada um?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Sleep

[`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) - ou também [`TimeUnit.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep(long)) - faz com que a *thread* atual pare de executar por um intervalo de tempo pré-determinado.

## Wait

[`Object.wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) também faz com que a thread atual pare de executar, porém sem um tempo determinado. A execução continua quando outra thread chama o método `notify` no mesmo objeto, ou seja, a thread pausada é notificada que pode continuar.

## Diferenças

Enquanto `sleep` e um método que só funciona se chamado no objeto que faz referência à thread atual, `wait` e `notify` podem ser chamados em qualquer objeto compartilhado entre a thread que espera e a thread que acorda a outra. Para chamar os métodos, é necessário que seja adquirido o *lock* no objeto, ou seja, que haja um bloco de sincronização `synchronized (objeto)`.

Uma confusão comum é que existe uma versão do `wait` que aceita um tempo como parâmetro, um *timeout*. Isto não é a mesma coisa. O *timeout* é o tempo máximo que a thread vai ficar parada esperando para ser notificada. Se o tempo limite for excedido, vai haver uma interrupção e uma `InterruptedException` será lançada.

É comum ter a intuição incorreta de que chamar `wait` numa referência a uma outra thread significa esperar que ela termine antes de continuar a thread atual. Na verdade, o método [`Thread.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) existe para isso. Se chamar `wait` numa outra thread, tudo o que vai ocorrer é que o programa vai ficar esperando alguém chamar `notify`.

Se várias threads chamarem `wait` no mesmo objeto, `notify` vai acordar apenas uma delas. Para acordar todas existe o `notifyAll`.

## Objetivos

O objetivo do `sleep` é simplesmente pausar a execução por um tempo. Dificilmente uma aplicação comum terá algum motivo real para isto.

Já `wait` e `notify` tem como alvo sincronizar uma execução concorrente usando um ou mais objetos compartilhados.

Um exemplo comum seria a implementação de duas threads, um produtor e um consumidor, utilizando um objeto que é uma fila de processamento compartilhada. Se não houver itens produzidos a serem processados, o consumidor chamada o método `wait` no objeto da fila. Quando o produtor colocar algo para ser processado, ele chama `notify` na fila para acordar o consumidor.

Answer (score 2):

O `wait`, espera terminar o processo filho para poder continuar a execução do sistema.

Já o `sleep`, faz com que a *Thread* durma por um determinado tempo antes dela voltar a execução (se não usar threads, a pausa se aplica ao seu processo).

Comment: Esta definição de `wait` (esperar terminar o processo filho) não é muito exata, embora seja uma das possibilidades de uso junto com o `notify`.